# Android - setting setOffscreenPageLimit with ViewPager2 causes screen distortion on orientation change

Tags: android, android-viewpager2

I have 3 fragments in my app, each represents one activity and using viewpager2. When device orientation changes from vertical, to horizontal and setOffscreenPageLimit is set, then fragment content does not fit to screen. Instead 1/2 of two different neighbour fragments are displayed. This is happening only if user swipes to fragment with index 1 and higher. Left part of the screen shows part of the left neighbour fragment and right part shows part of right one. What also happens if last fragment is selected and screen orientation is changed to horizontal, then right part of the screen remains blank.

[image]

This can be overcome by manifest modification, removing orientation tag

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|screenSize" />
```

But this is not the solution for me as i want activity is not reloaded on orientation change.

my Viepager2 implementation:

```
vpPager2 = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);

arrayList.add(new ImagesFragment());
arrayList.add(new EnvironmentFragment());
arrayList.add(new SensorScreenFragment());

viewpagerfragmentadapter = new ViewPagerFragmentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), getLifecycle());

// use a number higher than half your fragments to avoid re-loading fragment on every swipe
vpPager2.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
vpPager2.setOrientation(ViewPager2.ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL);
vpPager2.setAdapter(viewpagerfragmentadapter);
```

Example if fragment #2

```
    public class EnvironmentFragment extends Fragment {

        @Override
            public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        
                return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_environment_constraint, container, false);
        
            }

... rest of activity code 

}
```

Any ides how this behaviour could be fixed?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Two pieces of fragments are displayed on orientation change to landscape with ViewPager2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67895268/two-pieces-of-fragments-are-displayed-on-orientation-change-to-landscape-with-vi)

Answer (score 1):

It looks when this line is removed:

```
vpPager2.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
```

The odd behaviour stops and orientation change rendering works as expected, but i am not sure what is causing this.

Comment: issue is documented as bug here: https://issuetracker.google.com/175796502